# Multi Threaded Windows Application uses more memory when idle

Tags: c#, multithreading, memory

I've got a technical question around memory usage and multi-threaded applications.

My scenario is that I've built a server application (in C#) that is constantly running and updating DB info periodically (every minute). The application is split into two threads. The first thread handles the UI. The second thread handles all the grunt work in a continuous loop (until Tasks flag = false). When the second thread completes its tasks it goes into sleep for 60 seconds after which it loops and does it again.

The application runs happily without memory issues or resource issues but I've noticed something strange which I don't understand.

When the application is working (doing its tasks), it utilizes 100% of the available CPU and the memory drops to 80k kb. But when the tasks are finished and the second thread goes into sleep the memory goes up to 180k kb.

I'd appreciate it if anyone can explain this?

Code

```
private void BackgroundWorker1()
    {
        BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
        bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;

        bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(
        delegate(object o, DoWorkEventArgs args)
        {
            BackgroundWorker b = o as BackgroundWorker;
            {
                while (Tasks)
                {
                    try
                    {

                        SetValue(System.DateTime.Now.ToString() + " - Opening DB Connection \r\n");
                        GlobalVars.WiFiToolDataSource.Open();
                        SetValue(System.DateTime.Now.ToString() + " - Starting Task \r\n");
                        TicketFunctions.GetBOSSTickets();
                        SetValue(System.DateTime.Now.ToString() + " - Got Tickets from BOSS \r\n");
                        EmailFunctions.GetEmails("");
                        SetValue(System.DateTime.Now.ToString() + " - Got Emails from Inbox \r\n");
                        EmailFunctions.GetEmails("WiFI Survey Archive");
                        SetValue(System.DateTime.Now.ToString() + " - Got Emails from Archive \r\n");
                        EmailFunctions.checkEmails("BodyText", GlobalVars.ApplicationData + "Emails");
                        SetValue(System.DateTime.Now.ToString() + " - Loaded Emails in DB \r\n");
                        EmailFunctions.CreateEmailIndexes();
                        SetValue(System.DateTime.Now.ToString() + " - Created Email Indexes \r\n");
                        TicketFunctions.UpdateTicketList();
                        SetValue(System.DateTime.Now.ToString() + " - Updated Tickets \r\n");
                        TicketFunctions.BuildTicketKB();
                        SetValue(System.DateTime.Now.ToString() + " - Finished Build Knowledge Base \r\n");
                        SetValue(System.DateTime.Now.ToString() + " - Finished Refresh \r\n");
                        if (!Tasks)
                            break;
                        if (System.DateTime.Now.Hour.ToString("HH") == "00")
                        {
                            if (newFile)
                            {
                                string CDate = System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).ToString("ddMMyyyy");
                                string FileName = "QA_LOG_" + CDate + ".txt";
                                System.IO.File.WriteAllText(GlobalVars.ApplicationData + @"QA Server Log\" + FileName, textBox1.Text);
                                ClearValue();
                                newFile = false;
                            }
                        }
                        if (System.DateTime.Now.Hour.ToString("HH") == "01")
                        {
                            newFile = true;
                        }
                        Thread.Sleep(60000);

                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        SetValue("Error : " + e.ToString() + " \r\n"); ;
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        GlobalVars.WiFiToolDataSource.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        bw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(
        delegate(object o, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs args)
        {
            SetValue(System.DateTime.Now.ToString() + " - Complete \r\n");                
        });

        bw.RunWorkerAsync();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Odds are one of the later tasks that you have is one that is more memory intensive, while the earlier tasks take longer but don't consume as much memory.

Given that you're sleeping for 60 seconds, there's a high chance that a garbage collection will run sometime during that time period, thus bringing the memory back down before the start of the next iteration.

Without knowing the specifics of your functions, going into any more detail wouldn't be possible.

Comment: Thanks guys, makes a bit of sense. I clearly need to ramp up my knowledge in memory management.

Answer (score 0):

The Computer ultimately wants everything to be as close to the CPU as possible so while the threads active, it will try and move things out of memory into the various levels of cache. When the thread goes to sleep the computer will try to free up the different levels of cache, to make room for active tasks, moving things further and further away from the CPU ( back to memory or disk ).

Comment: Information that's in the cache is still in memory.  It's cached *in addition* to being in memory, not instead of, as such adding/removing things from the cache doesn't change the memory footprint of the application.

Comment: Interesting.  Thank you for the clarification.